# How to create subquery with distinct in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two ORACLE SQL queries which work well:

```
SELECT COUNT(SEG_ID) INTO totalUniqueSegments FROM CAR_RENTAL_SERVICES;

SELECT DISTINCT SEG_ID FROM CAR_RENTAL_SERVICES;
```

But I need to combine them. I'd like my count to consider only unique seg_id.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(SEG_ID)INTO totalUniqueSegments FROM CAR_RENTAL_SERVICES WHERE SEG_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SEG_ID FROM CAR_RENTAL_SERVICES);
```

But I'm getting the error 'missing expression'. It should be fairly simple but I'm not very experienced. Thanks.

EDIT: this `COUNT(SEG_ID)INTO` was changed to this `COUNT(SEG_ID) INTO` (with space).
Now the error is 'missing expression'

Comment: Maybe you're missing a column name for `COUNT(SEG_ID)` since you're putting it into another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEG_ID) FROM CAR_RENTAL_SERVICES;
```

Use the below query, If You want to demonstrate the same using a sub-query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(
     SELECT DISTINCT seg_id 
     FROM   car_rental_services
     );
```

Comment: Your solution is great and it works. However I needed to demonstrate using a sub-query for a school exercise. Is it possible in this case or should I abandon the idea ? Thanks ! (I can mark your solution in any case)

Comment: @PrincessLilly, Please find the updated answer with sub-query.